# Get range of dates by month between range of dates

Tags: php

I have these dates:

```
start date:  5/08/2011
end date:  16/11/2011
```

I need get the follow ranges according to the month dynamically:

```
5/08/2011-31/08/2011
1/09/2011-30/09/2011
1/10/2011-31/10/2011
1/11/2011-16/11/2011
```

I need get ranges of dates dynamically by month from a start date and end date.

Can you help me?  Thanks.

Comment: all the steps you need to solve this can be found in the **Related** section to the right.

Comment: I'm sorry for the question, is a wrong question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$start_date = list($sDay, $sMonth, $sYear) = explode("/", "05/08/2011");
$end_date   = list($eDay, $eMonth, $eYear) = explode("/", "16/11/2011");

$startMonth = $sMonth;
do
{
    $mk = mktime(0, 0, 0, $sMonth, 1, $sYear);
    $mY = date("mY", $mk);
    $endFormat = "t/m/Y";

    if ($sMonth == $startMonth)
    {
        $mk = mktime(0, 0, 0, $sMonth, $sDay, $sYear);
    }
    else if ($mY == $eMonth . $eYear)
    {
        $endFormat = $eDay . "/m/Y";
    }

    echo date("d/m/Y", $mk)    . " - " . 
         date($endFormat, $mk) . "<br />";

    $sMonth++;
}
while ($eMonth . $eYear > $mY);

?>
```

Comment: Marcio thanks for your answer. If you idea is this , you should not to answer my question. I'm sorry for this question.

Comment: Guys! I don't want to be misunderstood. You know, some users doesn't answer if they think you don't tryied your all chances and codes. I just answered without questioning you cause I think you will study my code, my answer, and not for other reason!!

Comment: Your code is very useful for me and I think that I learn with your answer. Before to ask I found the answer of kolyaflash and other codes.  I am beginning with PHP and I don't understand very well about the dates and I didn't think that this question is obvious or easy of answering.  For me is not easy because I am beginning.  I'm sorry for generate the negative comments and negative points in this post.

Comment: You're right, is not so easy to do that. There's a bit of logic and date knowledge. I answered your question to help you and for any other reason. I think your question was down-voted because you have posted no code of yours, people think you just asked without a try. But don't worry no need to be sorry, we're all here to help and learn !!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php


function dateRange( $first, $last, $step = '+1 month', $format = 'd/m/Y' ) {

    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime( $first );
    $last = strtotime( $last );

    while( $current <= $last ) {

        $dates[] = date( $format, $current );
        $current = strtotime( $step, $current );
    }

    return $dates;
}
print_r( dateRange( '2010/01/26', '2010/08/05') );
?>
```

Comment: @Márcio, yes. Its just an example and universal method. I want to tell him the direction to solve. But you are great, you did it!

Comment: this code doesn't generate the dates as my question but this code is useful.  Thanks.

Comment: kolyaflash try the dates so: print_r( dateRange( '2012/07/26', '2011/08/05') ); in format ('Y/m/d').

Comment: If he doesn't like to study and learn he will ask in any forum on web as he did here. But if he wants to evolve himself he can't study my code, if not, we can't do anything. The answer he can found everywhere. ;)

Comment: @cabita Input format is Y/m/d, but output is as you wish (d/m/Y).

Comment: @Márcio, yes. I'm sorry. I should not write it. This is far from being solved.

Comment: @kolyaflash no man, I didn't say that way. All help is useful. I just justified why I answered him with the full code.

Comment: Marcio thanks for your answer.  If you idea is this , you should not to answer my question.  I'm sorry for this question.